# If two change functions act on the same id which will take precedence?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, operator-precedence

I have a JavaScript working on some PHP code as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $("#hosted_prev_no").change(function(){ 
        $("#attend").show();
        $("#eligible").hide();
    });
    $("#hosted_prev_yes").change(function(){
        $("#attend").hide();
        $("#eligible").show();
    });
    $("#attend_prev_yes").change(function(){
        $("#eligible").show();
    });
    $("#attend_prev_yes").change(function(){
        $("#eligible").hide();    
    });
```

The php code is as follows:

```
  <div class="full row column">
    <label id="hosted_prev_label" for="hosted_prev" class="required">Have you hosted a Road Scholar program for Stetson University in the past?</label>
    <label id="hosted_prev_yes_label" for="hosted_prev_yes">Yes</label>
    <input id="hosted_prev_yes" name="hosted_prev" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    <label id="hosted_prev_no_label" for="hosted_prev_no">No</label>
    <input id="hosted_prev_no" name="hosted_prev" type="radio" value="No" /><br />
    <div id="attend" class="hidden">
      <label id="atend_prev_label" for="atend_prev" class="required">Have you attended at least one Stetson Road Scholar program in the past?</label>
      <label id="attend_prev_yes_label" for="attend_prev_yes">Yes</label>
      <input id="attend_prev_yes" name="attend_prev" type="radio" value="Yes" />
      <label id="attend_prev_no_label" for="hosted_prev_no">No</label>
      <input id="attend_prev_no" name="attend_prev" type="radio" value="No" /><br />
    </div>
    <div id="ineligible" class="hidden">
      <p>All hosts are required to attend at least one Stetson University Road Scholar program before they may host p program. You may apply again once you have attended a Stetson University Road Scholar program. Thank you for your interest.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="eligible" class="full row column hidden">
    <h2>Cohost Information</h2>
    <label id="is_cohost_label" for="is_cohost" class="required">Will you be hosting with anyone?</label>
    <label id="is_cohost_yes_label" for="is_cohost_yes">Yes</label>
    <input id="is_cohost_yes" name="is_cohost" type="radio" value="Yes" />
    <label id="is_cohost_no_label" for="is_cohost_no">No</label>
    <input id="is_cohost_no" name="is_cohost" type="radio" value="No" /><br />
  </div>
```

The problem is that the second radios not displaying the "`eligible`" div. How do you know which change function has precedence here?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S2aJU/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the same element twice:

```
$("#attend_prev_yes").change(function(){
    $("#eligible").show();
});
$("#attend_prev_yes").change(function(){
    $("#eligible").hide();    
});
```

I think what you need is:

```
$("#attend_prev_yes").change(function(){
    $("#eligible").show();
});
$("#attend_prev_no").change(function(){
    $("#eligible").hide();    
});
```

Comment: That was the problem. The other part of the question still is there do. Do the two cancel each other out in my example or does one take precedence over the other?

Comment: When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the normal event propagation path.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/bind/